# Roadside wheel change metal d clip

Tags: tires, wheels

I'm trying to change the wheel on my peugeot partner (on the roadside) I'm not sure what this metal d clip on the wheel is? Could anyone advise how I remove this to change the wheel and what it actually does?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like part of the plastic wheel trim clip system.

Remove the plastic trim and continue as normal, ie loosen bolts /nuts and jack up etc..